# WordPress page template elementor issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, elementor

To keep this short and clear, I have created a page template and I cannot seem to add any element freely, as I'm stuck only by adding an element on top but not being able to post anything after the product table.

This is the code of the template that I'm working on:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: New Campaign Template
 */
get_header();

if(!isset($main_class)){
  $main_class = '';
}
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();
do_action('shop_template_all_products');
endwhile;

?>

   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here is a gif to explain what is happening:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Kqf.gif)

What I need is to be able to add elements at the bottom.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

you should create shortcode of products that you are displaying with do_action('shop_template_all_products'); and use it with default templete in order to add content above and below it.

Comment: How would it be possible to create a shortcode with the code that  I have?

I would appreciate your help on this!